# Accuracy of "Events" in ode45 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I'm consider a problem of integrating until an event occurs using ode45 in Matlab, as in here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-662913.html#f1-670140

Is there a way to control how accurately Matlab computes the event location? More specifically, the events tell you to solve on ODE until one finds a zero of the `value` parameter, but how small is `value`?  Is there a way to specify how small I want `value` to be when the integration terminates?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to control how accurately Matlab computes the event
>   location?

The short answer appears to be "no, but it's at machine precision anyway". Matlab's `ode45` (and the rest, like `ode15s`, `ode23`, etc.) calls a function called `odezero`, which does the work of computing the zero events of the ODE integrators. Here are the relevant lines in `odezero` where the tolerance is set:

```
tol = 128*max(eps(t),eps(tnew));
tol = min(tol, abs(tnew - t));
```

From this, you can see two things: (1) there is no dependence on any user options and (2) even if you had control, you couldn't set it any smaller because the tolerance is 128*eps.

> Is there a way to specify how small I want value to be when the
>   integration terminates?

Matlab's ODE event detectors don't look for `value` going to zero or getting close to zero, it looks for it *crossing* zero. If you want to look for a particular value of the ODE crossing a certain value, then have the event function return the difference between the solution and the desired threshold.